# Getting list of all the open routes generated by sails js(Node js MVC framework)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Hello I am using sails js for my web application development. Sails automatically generate some shortcut routes, some blueprints routes, some action routes and some populated routes. I have find all the routes generated by sails. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Sails, at least for version 0.12, does not have a command to list all the routes.

There is a variable that includes information about all the custom routes. You can open sails console and type it:

```
$ sails console
> sails.config.routes
```

Because you cannot see the routes automatically generated by, say, the Blueprint API, there is an open issue around that. See the pull request discussion at https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/2659

You may also find this closed issue helpful: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2849

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
`sails.config.routes`
```

to get all routes

[Issue to get all routes](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/2659#issuecomment-77417170)

Comment: It only returns those routes, which I have mentioned in config/routes.js file. It is not showing sails automatically generate routes

Comment: I think to get all routes there is some issue created on Github, please have a look https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/2659#issuecomment-77417170